# Getting Java.lang.Unsatisfiedlink error on docker machine if the robot class code gets executed for taking full page screenshot

Tags: java, docker, selenium-webdriver

I want to take full page screenshot including the date and time at the bottom and with the URL. I'm using robot class method (createScreenCapture) by taking the screen size as rectangle object and sending it into the createScreenCapture as below:

```
public static void fullScreenshot(){
        Robot robot;
        byte[] bytes;
        try{
             robot=new Robot();
            Rectangle rect =new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            BufferedImage screenshot=robot.createScreenCapture(rect);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(screenshot, "png", baos);
            bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            String name="Test2031";
            CMTestUtil.updateLog(name);
            scenario.attach(bytes,"image/png",name);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("FullScreen shot not taken");
        }
    }
```

Above code works perfectly fine for me on local and it takes full page screenshot with the URL and Date and time in the bottom. But on executing the same on docker container using git lab it throws error as below:

[image]

Not sure why it is causing the problem.